# Activity Maps reinicia toda vez que minimizo

Tags: java, android, android-activity, maps

Bom, no android 4.2.1 está funcionando, mas em outro dispositivo com android 4.2.2 ele reinicia, ou seja, não salva o estado da activity, esse problema só aparece com as activitys que uso mapa, nas outras funciona tranquilo. Abaixo está o inicio do cabeçalho da activity.

```
   public class Map_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback
            , com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_);
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é o seguinte, quando o aplicativo perde o foco, se dá início a um ciclo que faz parte do Ciclo de vida de um aplicativo Android, quando uma Activity não é mais visível (nem no foreground) o método `onStop` é chamado isso significa que a partir deste momento, o sistema (cujo gerenciamento tem algumas mudanças de versão para versão do Android) pode decidir destruir essa activity (chamando o método `onDestroy()`).

**Android Life Cicle:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o sistema destrói a sua Activity, ele armazena o estado da Activity nos Bundles, para isso todas as Views precisam ter ID's para serem identificados.

Porém, nem sempre o Android acerta, e restaura tudo como você deseja, sendo assim, se é importante que a Activity mantenha determinado comportamento, o ideal é que você não dependa do Android para fazer isso e garanta que em qualquer versão, sua view manterá o comportamento.

Então, você precisa sobrescrever o método `onSaveInstanceState` e `onRestoreInstanceState`, e faça o tratamento dos dados salvos no `onCreate`

Exemplo:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

Fonte [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Opa, mas nos casos de alguns dialog aberto, como posso fz isso?

Comment: Cara, posso estar errado, mas o Dialog estende um objeto, então creio que você consiga armazenar o objeto inteiro na Bundle e exibi-lo novamente. Outra solução é usar um DialogFragment, assim você pode cuidar do ciclo dele a parte, como nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557265/prevent-dialog-dismissal-on-screen-rotation-in-android/15729764#15729764